# Trying to use driver to animate rigid body animated-value

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, drivers

I am trying to simulate something like a drilling-effect. I have a box out of a big amount of little boxes, all defined as rigid bodies. I have added a driver to the "Animated"-switch calculated out of frame number X and Z coordinates, like this

```
frame<(1-var1)*200+(var+10)*2
```

`var1` is the x-location, `var2` the z-location of the box.

When starting to create the physic-animation, it looks as if it is working.
The vortex-force works on that boxes that have a false for this driver.
But some boxes reach positions that re-set the "animated"-value to true. These parts start to flip around the scene, bound in something like a loop.

I am looking for a way to make sure that a box being set to unanimated stays this way until the last frame.

Any solution for this?